# download with gdown a file in a folder with original name

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

i am trying to download a file called file.zip from google drive with gdown in colab

```
!gdown url -O /out
```

When checking the out folder the file name is something like zips2dkqipb0ntmp
instead of file.zip
also try with

```
gdown.download(url, "/out")
```

also bad results

Comment: Use the following code


`output_pth = "{desired_folder_path}/file.zip"
gdown.download(url, output, quiet=False)`